# laravel eloquent get min value from two field in same column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.6

My Database is like this

```
id |  product_id |   cost1 |   cost2
1       2          33      20
2       2          25      36
3       3          10      15
```

I need result of min cost( min value of cost1 and cost2) of product_id 2
I am using laravel framework.
Any one help me?

Comment: Show us what you got!

Comment: Do you want MySQL code or laravel - ORM code?

Comment: I need in laravel eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get min value from multiple fields like this:

```
$query = DB::table('product')
    // to get multiple min values
    ->selectRaw('min(cost1) AS minCost1, min(cost2) AS minCost2') 
    ->where('product_id', 2);
```

to get min value from min values try this:

```
$query = DB::table('product')    
    // get least value from min of two fields
    ->selectRaw(' LEAST(min(cost1), min(cost2)) AS finalMin') 
    ->where('product_id', 2);
```

[LEAST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) will return the smallest element

Comment: how to print value ?

Comment: add `dd($yourVariable)` and post the result in your question